# Bootstrap 3 - Dropdown don't work & work with mouse over

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This probably it's something very easy to solve, but i'm not getting this.

My drop-down isn't working.
I just copy and paste the code of documents.
And, how I can change for the menu work with "on mouse over" ?
Thanks

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CurMZ/)

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
 <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
 </div>

 <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
 </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML alone is not enough for it to work. You've only included the `bootstrap.css` file but the [dropdown](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns) component at the least requires `dropdown.js` to work. In your fiddle I included the entire `bootstrap.js` file from [bootstrapcdn](http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/)

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/CurMZ/1/

Comment: I knew it would be something easy. Is there any way to change that is "on mouse over" ?

Comment: One option is to modify the `dropdown.js` component of bootstrap or you can use [this plugin](http://cameronspear.com/demos/twitter-bootstrap-hover-dropdown/)

Answer (score 2):

next time use Bootply: http://bootply.com/80635
It's jsfiddle built for Bootstrap.